# No me ejecutan los scripts en Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, laravel-5

[image: En esta imagen estoy haciendo el llamado de la sección 'scritps']

[![En esta parte estan los 2 scripts que estoy ejecutando, pero ninguno de los 2 me ejecuta al momento de ejecutar el sitio web.][2]][2]

Necesito ayuda, no sé si en Laravel 5.6 se necesita algo extra para ejecutar los scripts, o si alguien sabe el por qué no me ejecutan estos codigos, le agradezco mucho! gracias!
asi es como estoy llamando los archivos en las carpetas:

```
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.min.js') }}"> 
    </script>


    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#name, #slug").stringToSlug({
                callback: function(text){
                    $("#slug").val(text);
                }
            });
        });

        CKEDITOR.config.height = 400;
        CKEDITOR.config.width  = 'auto';
        CKEDITOR.replace('body');
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: configuraste que el helper "asset", tome desde la raíz del proyecto? ya que que si no es así, por defecto, toma la carpeta public hacia adentro

Comment: vendor es una carpeta que esta en tu directorio public?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que comentas en tu código, tienes la llamada de los archivos "stringToSlug.js" y "ckeditor,js" duplicados (dentro y fuera del bloque "@section('scripts')"). Intenta eliminar los que se encuentran fuera del bloque y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: ya eso lo hice, aca esta asi porque no me mostraba esas 2 lineas donde los llamaba.